# return a value if null or not null. tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have recently written a report using a variation of this SQL Statement:

```
select project.*, TF.*, TW.*, TR.*, TH.* from
(select sum(Quantity) as FQty from unitType where Type = 'F' group by type) TF, 
(select sum(Quantity) as WQty from unitType where Type = 'W' group by type) TW, 
(select sum(Quantity) as RQty from unitType where Type = 'R' group by type) TR, 
(select sum(Quantity) as HQty from unitType where Type = 'H' group by type) TH
```

The problem is that if a project doesnt have a unit type then the sql statement of that unit type returns nothing which then makes my whole statement return nothing. I have been trying to figure out how to get it to return a 0 if null, but nothing seems to work for me. I have tried Case but it tells me something about "isnull is an invalid column name" i have also tries "if exists" but that just throws a syntax error.

any suggestions?

Comment: I have a project with all 4 types that the sql works perfectly on. but if 1 type is missing then the whole report for the project returns null.

Comment: Where is that `project` table/alias in your `FROM` clause?

Comment: this is a severely trimmed down statement. i guess i could have trimmed it down to just one of the selects.

Comment: In your question there is `FROM unitType`, which looks like a table's name. But bit below you are stateing *if a project doesnt have a unit type*, which rather looks like a column's name... Please provide details about your table(s) structure(s). In general: A list of sources (`... FROM tblA,tblB,tblC`) is an outdated syntax for a `CROSS JOIN` and should result as *each-with-each* (cartesian product). I really doubt, that this is what you need...

Comment: we work on a project and the unitType table contains a row for each specific unit of the project. not all projects have a unit of every type. so if the project is missing the F type, it returns as 0 rows, which in turn causes the sql statement to return 0 rows, which causes all fields in the report the SQL is powering to return null values.

If a project has all 4 types, then the report shows as working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
OUTER APPLY (select sum(Quantity) as FQty from unitType where Type = 'F' group by type) TF
OUTER APPLY (select sum(Quantity) as WQty from unitType where Type = 'W' group by type) TW 
OUTER APPLY (select sum(Quantity) as RQty from unitType where Type = 'R' group by type) TR 
OUTER APPLY (select sum(Quantity) as HQty from unitType where Type = 'H' group by type) TH
```

You got 0 rows because of the CROSS JOIN you used. The number of rows would be `...* number of row of TF * number of row of TW *...`, and imagine a product where one of the number is 0, then the result is 0.

Comment: immediately gives me an Syntax error near 'OUTER' in VS2015.

Comment: VS 2015? Why don't you test your query independently first.

Comment: it's the tool that i was given to use.

Answer (score 0):

try with case when:
`SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS FQTY FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN QUANTITY IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE QUANTITY END QUANTITY FROM....)`

Comment: this works perfectly if there are rows returned for the statement. but returns nothing when used on one of the types that have no rows.